# How to simplify a code for student grades with pandas and python

Tags: pandas

Which is the best and shorter way to get to code this and end up with an outcome like below other than this long way I have done it?
My data is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ENG':[10,3,5,6,3],'KIS':[9,5,7,9,10],'BIO':[10,'',4,'',4]})
```

This is my expected outcome

```
  ENG KIS BIO
  B+   9  10    
  D    5        
  C-   7  4   
  C    9      
  D    1  4
```

And this is what I have coded to get it.

```
grade = []
for points in df["ENG"] :
    if points >= 12:
        grade.append( "A")
    elif points >= 11:
        grade.append("A-")
    elif points >= 10:
        grade.append("B+")
    elif points >= 9:
        grade.append( "B")
    elif points >= 8:
        grade.append("B-")
    elif points >= 7:
        grade.append("C+")
    elif points >= 6:
        grade.append("C")
    elif points >= 5:
        grade.append("C-")
    elif points >= 4:
        grade.append("D+")
    elif points >= 3:
        grade.append("D")
    elif points >= 2:
        grade.append("D-") 
    elif points == "":
        grade.append("")
    elif points >0:
        grade.append("E")
    else:
        grade.append("")
df["ENG"] = grade
print(df)
```

To get for 'KIS' and 'BIO' I had to repeat the whole process for the two. Could I just have one and apply to all the subjects?

Comment: Take a look at [`pandas.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

Comment: I tried that also, couldn't get it, @cs95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are all values integers and no negative values is possible use

First can create `dict` by all values and then use `map` with replace higher like `11` to `A`:

```
d = {1:"E",2:'D-', 3: 'D', 
     4:'D+',5:'C-',6:'C',
     7:'C+',8:'B-',9:'B',
     10:'B-','':''}

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(d)).fillna('A')
print (df)
  ENG KIS BIO
0  B-   B  B-
1   D  C-    
2  C-  C+  D+
3   C   B    
4   D  B-  D+
```

Comment: Let me see what it does.